# How to store coordinates effectively if they are being generated every 10 ms

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

I have an iPad app that gets X,Y and Z coordinates from the gyros every 10 ms. What I need to do is store these in the ram until they can be persisted at a convenient time. What is an efficient way of doing this. My first thought was to use a NSMutableArray, but I don't know if calling `[array addObject]` every 10ms is a good idea in terms of performance. Would it be better to create a linked list or use some other storage method?

Comment: Why are you persisting them?  Are they valuable after being a certain age?  (i.e. are these values interesting from yesterday?)

Comment: Yes I need to keep them all, they are to be extracted from the iPad later and analysed.

Comment: video games are rendering entire scenes in < 16ms in order to sustain 60fps framerate. a single call to addObject will be fine. :)

Comment: see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html if you want to time small pieces of code accurately. that will allow you to figure out just how much you can do in your 10ms window.

Comment: I would first test the IO bandwidth towards the persistent storage. You are generating a huge amount of data and writing it to the persistent storage can also become a bottleneck or cause lags. I have never tried iPad though, only 16 bit micro-controllers with SD card.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil...just start with `NSMutableArray` and see what you get...

Answer (score 2):

Let's be specific.

3 float x 100 per second x 60 seconds per minute x 1 save opportunity in 60 minutes = 4320000

It's only 4.2 MB per hour and mean nothing to the capacity and processing power of iPad.

Just NSMutableArray will do.

Comment: Slight exaggeration, since it'd be storing NSNumbers or NSValues rather than scalar floats, but yeah, it should still be well within what NSMutableArray can do.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this link:  [a C array that plays nicely with NSObject pointers](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=137) 
It should be right up your alley....

That said, I would use an NSMutableArray until you decide it is not providing the performance you desire.